# Passing variables to javascript events on struts 2 tags

Tags: javascript, select, struts2

I have a simple but annoying problem
I have a List of an object which successfully populates a `<s:select>` tag. The tag is as follows(please don't mind the spanish names or info:

```
<s:select name="curProfesor.pais" value="%{curProfesor.pais}" list="paises" listValue="nombre" headerKey="" headerValue="Seleccione" label="País de Residencia:"  onchange="changer(1,???})"/>
```

and the structure of the class of the list is:

```
public class Pais{
    private int id;
    private int iso_num;
    private String iso2;
    private String iso3;
    private String nombre;
```

the problem is depicted as ??? and it is that, no matter how I try it, I'm not able to pass information from the list to the "onchange" function, what I want to pass is the id of the object, and I have tried using OGNL brackets (%{}) and it doesn't seem to work.

Any help on this matter would be highly appreciated

EDIT: What I am trying to pass is the id of the current selected object, that is the id of the selected value of the `<s:select>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing the two concepts here: The struts tags are processed at the time of **rendering the page on the server**, while selecting the option happens on the client side, **after the page has been rendered**. So you can't use a struts tag to get the selected value unless you do a post back on change.

First, what you need to do is to get the Pais ID to be rendered as as the key of option elements as SKS already mentioned.

```
<s:select id="curProfesor_pais" name="curProfesor.pais" list="paises" listKey="id" listValue="nombre" headerKey="" headerValue="Seleccione" label="País de Residencia:" onchange="changer('curProfesor_pais')"/>
```

Note `listKey="id"`. I've also set an ID into the element so we can reference it easier.

Secondly, simply get the selected option ID by your JavaScript function.

```
function changer(elementId) {
  var selectedId = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
  alert(selectedId);
  //.......
}
```

Passing the element ID into the `changer` function is really not necessary unless you are planning to reuse the function.

Also note that `value="%{curProfesor.pais}"` is redundant, since the name of the element is the same - `curProfesor.pais`.

It's always good inspect the rendered HTML if something is not working as expected. If you would have inspected it, you would have noticed that the Pais ID is not being rendered as the option ID.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
<s:select list="mylist" listKey="myid" id="listid" onchange="callme()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function callme(){
  var v=document.getElementById('listid').value; //id of the selected element 
  alert(v);
}
</script>
```